# Ruby Thin/Rack strange multibyte characters behavior

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, rack, thin

**The question was re-written.**

I'm working on a simple web framework, and encountered a strange behavior from either Rack or the Thin server I'm using.

I tried to simplify the **config.ru** file as much as I could to gain the following code which reproduces the strange problem:

```
app = Proc.new do |env|
    content = "<p>عربي</p>"
    headers = {'Content-Type' => 'html/text; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length' => content.length.to_s}
    [200, headers, [content]]
end

run app
```

The code above is a normal Rack process, with the content a HTML paragraph which contains an Arabic word of four letters. Now, running Thin server: `thin start`, I was waiting for the source of the web page to be:

```
<p>عربي</p>
```

While it turned to be:

```
<p>عربي
```

Only, without the closing tag. The server works correctly if I inserted an English word instead of the Arabic one, so I concluded that the problem is related to the encoding or multibyte characters of Arabic.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2. The encoding of the file is UTF-8. And Ruby works well if I just try `puts "<p>عربي</p>"` in the console without the Rack or Thin server.

So, the problem is simply disappearing of a number of characters after the Arabic text when using Rack and Thin + the number of disappearing characters == the number of the Arabic characters in the text.

Any thoughts?

Comment: And what's the encoding of the string on line 3?

Comment: Line 3 has the same encoding of the file, UTF-8 as all the other strings.

Comment: Um..shouldn't it always return 2 as length. `puts` writes `\n` at the end of every string. I'm surprised the first line doesn't return 2 as well.

Comment: Anyway, normal ASCII characters are counted each as a single one, while every Arabic letter is counted as two separate characters, as if the encoding wasn't UTF-8.

Comment: So what are you setting the internal/external encodings for the stringio to?

Comment: This doesn't fix your problem, but you can simplify by replacing `buffer.rewind; buffer.read` with `buffer.string`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does `'Content-Length' => content.bytesize.to_s` improve things?

Comment: Yeah! It does! Thank you very much for that.. I'm sorry, I couldn't give that a vote up, it needs more reputation! Thanks everybody here.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you have to tell Ruby that the string has Arabic in it. Use the `force_encoding` method with whatever encoding supports those Arabic characters:

```
str.force_encoding("nameOfArabicEncoding")
```

Comment: The encoding is just UTF-8. It works good for strings, the problem is in StringIO objects + $stdout, I tried setting the encoding, which is anyway UTF-8, and nothing really happens.

Comment: @Omar Wait. What's your system encoding?

Comment: Locale? I'm not sure! But what I just know is that I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, if this can help, Aptana Studio, using UTF-8 as the default files' encoding, setting the default encoding as UTF-8 for my Ruby 1.9.3 `# encoding: utf-8` and everything works correctly as expected except StringIO in example above.

Comment: @Omar: Execute this and give me the result: `puts IO.new(1).external_encoding`.

Comment: Well, it returns just nothing. Just the \n of puts, leaving an empty line.

Comment: @Omar; Then change it to this: `puts STDIN.external_encoding`.

Comment: I did. STDIN => 'UTF-8', while STDOUT => nothing. But as I told you, normal string values work just as expected.

Comment: @Omar: Hm. I can't say I have a clue. Will you try just adding this to  your program: `puts buffer { puts "أ" }.encoding`?

Comment: Returns `UTF-8`. Looks like I have to delete/edit the question.. I noticed some new things, now the length works correctly, while the app still doesn't work correctly! Thanks for the help.